# How does One Find the PID of a Process Started with startproc?

Tags: daemon, pid, startproc

My understanding is that it's generally a good idea to create a PID file for daemon processes and that `startproc` is a good way to start these daemons.

I know that `startproc` takes -i and -p arguments that refer to PID files but it doesn't create a PID file or update it with the ID of the daemon process that it starts.  Echoing `$!` also doesn't give the right process identifier when `startproc` is used.

Does anyone have any advice as to how the PID of a daemon started with `startproc` can be elicited?

---

For what it's worth, I'm writing an rc script and want to start a JVM as a non-privileged user.  I don't really want to give this user a login shell (so `su -c "java ..." user` is not an option) and I don't really want a root process hanging around while the daemon is running either (which rules out `sudo -Eu user java ...`).  So, while I acknowledge that these are possible workarounds, I don't find either of them to be ideal.  Please feel free, though, to correct me if my assumptions about these alternatives are wrong.

Comment: What's your OS? Is `pidof` available? The manpage for startproc on http://www.linux-tutorial.info/modules.php?name=ManPage&sec=8&manpage=startproc doesn't know a `-i` option.

Comment: I'm using OpenSuSE 11.4.  `pidof` is available but given that there may be several JVMs running this may be tricky.

Comment: You could compare the `/proc/<pid>/cmdline` of each `pidof java` to determine if such a daemon is already running. Note that the cmdline args are separated by \0 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like nobody knows a way of doing this, then.

Instead, I just did what Tomcat basically does; write a shell script and invoke this from my service instead of invoking `java` directly.

This shell script also takes care of creating the PID file using `echo $!` after starting the JVM.  For shutdown, I've written a similar script that checks this PID file and removes it after a successful shutdown.  Both scripts are invoked using `sudo -Eu $USER script_name.sh` from the service.

Technically, this doesn't answer my question because the solution doesn't use `startproc` at all, but it works and avoids the cumbersome task of comparing command lines of running processes.

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem, tried something:

```
PID=$(startproc -p $PID_FILE <some parameters>)
echo $PID  > $PID_FILE
```

and it worked ... tried it at SLES 11 SP4

but at SLES 12 everything works complete different :(